# Draw "red squiggly line" in CHtmlEditCtrl

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, spell-checking, hunspell

I am working on building spellchecking functionality into my app which currently uses MFC's `CHtmlEditCtrl` control.

Is there a way of drawing one of those "red squiggly lines" that you see under spelling errors on the HTML control, underneath the word that I detect to be a spelling error?

The only way I can think of is to use the actual HTML to apply this style, and then strip it out upon the email being sent. This seems rather messy, as if the user starts applying underline styles to the text they could interfere with it.

Is there a way of doing this with drawing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/csexwb/LMEC8k3z16I

Comment: Yes I saw that Google group, the issue is isn't that one using the html underlining which will be retained when I save the html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interface you want is [IHTMLRenderStyle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa769064(v=vs.85).aspx). You pass this, once filled in, to the [AddSegment](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752373(v=vs.85).aspx) method of the of the [IHighlightRenderingServices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752374(v=vs.85).aspx) interface. Here's an [example](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/csexwb/LMEC8k3z16I/KUWjJQ-yvT0J) in (gasp) VB. I've done it in C++, years ago now though, and it worked nicely.